# Does 2D array need to know its size beforehand in C?

Tags: c, pointers, assembly, multidimensional-array, function-parameter

Comparing this 2 codes:

```
void foo(int rows, int cols, int **ar)
{
  printf("%d\n", ar[rows - 1][cols - 1]);
}
```

and

```
void foo(int rows, int cols, int ar[rows][cols])
{
  printf("%d\n", ar[rows - 1][cols - 1]);
}
```

for

```
int main()
{
  int ar[3][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
  foo(3, 2, ar);
}
```

The first foo, where there is just double-pointer, the program terminates. The second one, where the sizes are specified, prints the correct result. Why is that? Is not array passed as pointer to function anyway?

As per the assembly output, both leads to the same result. The point is calculating the offset from the beginning of the array. From the assembly, the first (`1`) number is stored `-32(%rbp)`, and the wanted result (`6`) is stored at `-12(%rbp)`. So both the assembly leads to result of `-32(%rbp) + 20` (after calculations involved).

The assembly of first:

```
.text
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "%d\n"
    .text
    .globl  foo
    .type   foo, @function
foo:
    endbr64 
    pushq   %rbp    #
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  #,
    subq    $16, %rsp   #,
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)  # rows, rows
    movl    %esi, -8(%rbp)  # cols, cols
    movq    %rdx, -16(%rbp) # ar, ar
# b.c:5:   printf("%d\n", ar[rows - 1][cols - 1]);
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax  # rows, tmp92
    cltq
    salq    $3, %rax    #, _2
    leaq    -8(%rax), %rdx  #, _3
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rax # ar, tmp93
    addq    %rdx, %rax  # _3, _4
    movq    (%rax), %rdx    # *_4, _5
# b.c:5:   printf("%d\n", ar[rows - 1][cols - 1]);
    movl    -8(%rbp), %eax  # cols, tmp94
    cltq
    salq    $2, %rax    #, _7
    subq    $4, %rax    #, _8
    addq    %rdx, %rax  # _5, _9

# FINAL ADDRESS RESOLUTION (IN REGISTER %rax) IS `-32(%rbp) + 20` (WHICH IS CORRECT ADDRESS OF NUMBER `6`)

# b.c:5:   printf("%d\n", ar[rows - 1][cols - 1]);
    movl    (%rax), %eax    # *_9, _10
    movl    %eax, %esi  # _10,
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi    #,
    movl    $0, %eax    #,
    call    printf@PLT  #
# b.c:6: }
    nop 
    leave   
    ret 
    .size   foo, .-foo
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    endbr64 
    pushq   %rbp    #
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  #,
    subq    $32, %rsp   #,
# b.c:9: {
    movq    %fs:40, %rax    # MEM[(<address-space-1> long unsigned int *)40B], tmp86
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)  # tmp86, D.2350
    xorl    %eax, %eax  # tmp86
# b.c:10:   int ar[3][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
    movl    $1, -32(%rbp)   #, ar[0][0]
    movl    $2, -28(%rbp)   #, ar[0][1]
    movl    $3, -24(%rbp)   #, ar[1][0]
    movl    $4, -20(%rbp)   #, ar[1][1]
    movl    $5, -16(%rbp)   #, ar[2][0]
    movl    $6, -12(%rbp)   #, ar[2][1]
# b.c:11:   foo(3, 2, ar);
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax #, tmp84
    movq    %rax, %rdx  # tmp84,
    movl    $2, %esi    #,
    movl    $3, %edi    #,
    call    foo #
    movl    $0, %eax    #, _10
# b.c:12: }
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rcx  # D.2350, tmp87
    subq    %fs:40, %rcx    # MEM[(<address-space-1> long unsigned int *)40B], tmp87
    je  .L4 #,
    call    __stack_chk_fail@PLT    #
.L4:
    leave   
    ret
```

And the second assembly is:

```
.text
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "%d\n"
    .text
    .globl  foo
    .type   foo, @function
foo:
    endbr64 
    pushq   %rbp    #
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  #,
    pushq   %rbx    #
    subq    $40, %rsp   #,
    movl    %edi, -36(%rbp) # rows, rows
    movl    %esi, -40(%rbp) # cols, cols
    movq    %rdx, -48(%rbp) # ar, ar
# b.c:3: void foo(int rows, int cols, int ar[rows][cols])
    movl    -40(%rbp), %eax # cols, cols.0_6
    movslq  %eax, %rdx  # cols.0_6, _1
    subq    $1, %rdx    #, _2
# b.c:3: void foo(int rows, int cols, int ar[rows][cols])
    movq    %rdx, -24(%rbp) # _2, D.2346
    movslq  %eax, %rdx  # cols.0_6, _4
    movq    %rdx, %rcx  # _4, _5
    movl    $0, %ebx    #, _5
# b.c:5:   printf("%d\n", ar[rows - 1][cols - 1]);
    movl    -36(%rbp), %edx # rows, tmp99
    subl    $1, %edx    #, _9
    movslq  %edx, %rdx  # _9, _10
# b.c:5:   printf("%d\n", ar[rows - 1][cols - 1]);
    cltq
    imulq   %rdx, %rax  # _10, _12
    leaq    0(,%rax,4), %rdx    #, _13
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rax # ar, tmp100
    addq    %rax, %rdx  # tmp100, _14
# b.c:5:   printf("%d\n", ar[rows - 1][cols - 1]);
    movl    -40(%rbp), %eax # cols, tmp101
    subl    $1, %eax    #, _15
# b.c:5:   printf("%d\n", ar[rows - 1][cols - 1]);
    cltq
    movl    (%rdx,%rax,4), %eax # (*_14)[_15], _16

# AGAIN, THE FINAL ADDRESS RESOLUTION (IN REGISTER %eax) IS -32(%rbp) + 20` (WHICH IS CORRECT ADDRESS OF NUMBER `6`)

    movl    %eax, %esi  # _16,
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi    #,
    movl    $0, %eax    #,
    call    printf@PLT  #
# b.c:6: }
    nop 
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rbx  #,
    leave   
    ret 
    .size   foo, .-foo
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    endbr64 
    pushq   %rbp    #
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  #,
    subq    $32, %rsp   #,
# b.c:9: {
    movq    %fs:40, %rax    # MEM[(<address-space-1> long unsigned int *)40B], tmp86
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)  # tmp86, D.2355
    xorl    %eax, %eax  # tmp86
# b.c:10:   int ar[3][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
    movl    $1, -32(%rbp)   #, ar[0][0]
    movl    $2, -28(%rbp)   #, ar[0][1]
    movl    $3, -24(%rbp)   #, ar[1][0]
    movl    $4, -20(%rbp)   #, ar[1][1]
    movl    $5, -16(%rbp)   #, ar[2][0]
    movl    $6, -12(%rbp)   #, ar[2][1]
# b.c:11:   foo(3, 2, ar);
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax #, tmp84
    movq    %rax, %rdx  # tmp84,
    movl    $2, %esi    #,
    movl    $3, %edi    #,
    call    foo #
    movl    $0, %eax    #, _10
# b.c:12: }
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rcx  # D.2355, tmp87
    subq    %fs:40, %rcx    # MEM[(<address-space-1> long unsigned int *)40B], tmp87
    je  .L4 #,
    call    __stack_chk_fail@PLT    #
.L4:
    leave   
    ret
```

So why both assembly uses the same address to yield the number `6` and yet one terminates, and the other prints?

Comment: A 2-dimensional array is not the same as an array of pointers.

Comment: Here I rather seek to answer, why in assembly the overall address is same in both, yet the results are different

Comment: moreover the stack in the second case is getting bigger (`subq    $40, %rsp`) in comparison to the first one (`subq    $16, %rsp`). Why is so?

Comment: @milanHrabos `int **ar` us not a _double array_.  `ar` is a _pointer_ to pointers.

Comment: @milanHrabos Save time.  With "The first foo, where there is just double-pointer, the program terminates.", enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: @milanHrabos Look at the lines in the 2nd version beginning with `imulq   %rdx, %rax  # _10, _12`. That's multiplying the row index by the length of the row, to get te offset to the row in the 2-d array.

Comment: @Barmar yes. The result of this instruction is `4`. That's correct (you can continue with the calculation and get to the correct result of the address for number `6`)

Comment: Why does the same address in `%rax` matter? It's not printing that address contents.

Comment: because the `rax` is holding the beggining of the array (of whatever type). So you from there you should get to the right result (which is `%rax + 20` -> number `6`). And you don't have to care about type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declared array

```
int ar[3][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
```

used in expression as a function argument is converted to the type `int ( * )[2]`. The type `int **` and `int ( * )[2]` are not compatible pointer types. So the first function call is incorrect and the function will invoke undefined behavior.

Pay attention to that in both function calls the same address is passed it is the address of the first element of the array.

But within the first function the dereferenced pointer `ar[rows - 1]` expects a pointer of the type `int *` while at this memory there is stored the value of the first element of the array.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int rows, int cols, int **ar)
{
    printf( "%p\n", ( void * )ar[rows - 1] );
}

int main(void) 
{
    int ar[3][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
    foo(3, 2, ( int ** )ar);
  
    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
0x600000005
```

That is elements of the array are interpreted as a pointer after dereferencing the pointer `ar`. So dereferencing the pointer one more results in accessing an arbitrary memory.

The assembler code is generated such a way that it interprets memory and values according to the type of the object stored in the memory. Different types of the same address of the memory results in generating different  assembler code.

Comment: Again. Here I rather seek to answer, why in assembly the overall address (of the correct number) is same in both, yet the results are different

Comment: @milanHrabos I think you just need to get your C grok level up to your assembly grok level.

Comment: @milanHrabos, the results are different because the assembly is different.  The assembly is different because the two types are not compatible.  That the addresses passed in to the function are the same is irrelevant.  You need both the address and the type of an object to interpret that object appropriately.  There's no particular reason why the address of an object of one type in one program should not be the same as the address of a different object of a different type in a different program.

Comment: @JohnBollinger well you said it. Different address, different type and different program should yield a different object. Why? Otherwise it wouldn't make sense. If it was not different object, then you can use whatever object from whatever address from whatever program as *your* object. That just makes no sense

Comment: @milanHrabos, I'm not entirely sure what you're failing to understand here, but maybe its that the incompatibility of the two types involved is not a mere technicality.  The two objects involved have different sizes, different layouts, and different contents.  If you tell the compiler to expect one but provide the other instead then what's surprising about reaping misbehavior?

Comment: @JohnBollinger but they do have same sizes, same layouts and content. Its the type of `int`. Both are the same. That's the point

Comment: @milanHrabos no, the arguments are *not* both of type `int`. Neither of them is. One is of type `int[][2]`, the other is of type `int**`. Neither is compatible with `int` in the first place. The first can be cast to the second by accident, but that's a fatal mistake. Both are pointer types, but dereferencing `int[][2]` *once* already yields an `int`, while the other type needs to be dereferenced *twice*!

Comment: No, @milanHrabos, they don't, and **that's** the point.  Arrays and pointers are completely different things, though language semantics disguise that to some extent.  An `int **` is a pointer to a pointer (to an `int`).  An `int ar[rows][cols]` is an array of arrays (of `int`), or if that appears in a function's parameter list then it is equivalent to `int (*ar)[cols]`, a pointer to an array of `int`.  You can safely reinterpret a pointer to an array as a pointer to the array's first element, but you *cannot* reinterpret a pointer to a pointer as a pointer to the thing its referent points to.

Comment: Incidentally, @milanHrabos, your compiler ought to be warning you about the type mismatch when the first version of `foo()` is used.  If it isn't, then either turn up the warning level or get a better compiler.

Comment: @JohnBollinger why not? Just don't think about type for a second. The pointer to whatever (to arrya, to another pointer, to ...) is just a number representing a address. And if the value it points is interpreted correctly, then you can just give a sh*t about the type). So again, why not?

Comment: @milanHrabos, you can't *not* think about the pointed to type.  Sure, you have a pointer in either case, and the two probably (but not necessarily) have the same representation.  So what? You're trying to access and use the data at the storage location to which the pointer points.  It matters whether *those* data have the form of a pointer to the `int`s you want or the form of the `int`s you want themselves.

Comment: That's true. But so does the assembly. In the first case `ar **int`. In the assembly, at the end of calculation, the `rax` is dereferenced one more time `movl    (%rax), %eax` (the parenthesis are dereferencing), whereas  the 2n array is not dereferencing. `movl  (%rdx,%rax,4), %eax`. Here the second case -> the address (rdx) is just adding (rax*4).

Comment: @JohnBollinger well now it makes fuc*ing sense. The first assembly derefences 2 times (so after the first calculation for rows, it dereferences and gets a number, not pointer), but then for the columns it dereferences for the second time but it dereferences not pointer, but number (here number `5`), which is not valid address.

Comment: Yes, @milanHrabos.  As I said from the beginning, the assembly is different because the types involved are not compatible.  Only one version is correct for the data actually residing at the pointed-to location, which is an expected consequence of the C pointer type accommodated by one being incompatible with the C pointer type accommodated by the other, notwithstanding that both are pointer types.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I agree, but for me the assembler is the holy of truth. So I need to see your statements and arguments in the assembly to actually believe you. So do I know

Comment: @milanHrabos: You wrote a function that loads a qword pointer from the pointed-to memory and then dereferences it.  The assembly reflects exactly what you wrote in C, based on what `int **ptr_ptr` means vs. `int arr2d[][]`.  You passed it a pointer to memory that just holds `int` elements, so it loaded a pair of those.  That's C UB, and in asm it does exactly what this answer describes.  The asm is always going to reflect the C semantics, so explaining the C semantics is a valid way to answer the question.  (And looking at the asm can help you understand the C semantics, sure.)

Answer (score 3):

`int **ar`:

```
                                       <----------cols------------------->
                                       +------+------+------+- ~ -+------+
                               ,------>| int  | int  | int  |     | int  |
+------+        ^ +------+    /        +------+------+------+- ~ -+------+
|int** +------->| | int* +---'         <----------cols------------------->
+------+        r +------+             +------+------+------+- ~ -+------+
                o | int* +------------>| int  | int  | int  |     | int  |
                w +------+             +------+------+------+- ~ -+------+
                s ~      ~             <----------cols------------------->
                | +------+             +------+------+------+- ~ -+------+
                | | int* +------------>| int  | int  | int  |     | int  |
                v +------*             +------+------+------+- ~ -+------+
```

`int (*ar)[cols]`:

```
                     <----------cols------------------->
+-------------+    ^ +------+------+------+- ~ -+------+
|int(*)[cols] +--->| | int  | int  | int  |     | int  |
+-------------+    r +------+------+------+- ~ -+------+
                   o | int  | int  | int  |     | int  |
                   w +------+------+------+- ~ -+------+
                   s ~      ~      ~      ~     ~      ~
                   | +------+------+------+- ~ -+------+
                   | | int  | int  | int  |     | int  |
                   v +------+------+------+- ~ -+------+
```